# recursive ML function unnest that accepts only a value of type 'a NestedList and return a list

Tags: sml

Here is an example
Examples:

```
- unnest;
val it = fn : 'a NestedList -> 'a list
(* [1,2,3] *)

- unnest(List [(Atom 1), (Atom 2), (Atom 3)]);
val it = [1,2,3] : int list
```

I was give

```
datatype 'a NestedList =
  Nil
| Atom of 'a
| List of 'a NestedList list;
```

What I have so far

```
fun unnest(Nil) = []
  | unnest(Atom(x)) = [x] 
  | unnest(List(x::xs)) = unnest(x);
```

which only gives the head part of the list and I do not know how to get to the rest of list.
I understand there is a way using concat and map and fn but is there without using library function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `unnest` to a `NestedList` value is meant to yield a plain old `list`. So we know the type of this function must be:

```
'a NestedList -> 'a list
```

When we apply `unnest` to a `List`, we need to recursively apply it to each element in that contained list.

There are two issues with your function.

1. It doesn't account for an empty list in the pattern-matching.
2. It only acts on the first item in a non-empty list.

If we `map` `unnest` to each element in that contained list, we'll get a list of lists. This isn't what we ultimately want, but we can work with it.

```
fun unnest(Nil) = []
  | unnest(Atom(x)) = [x] 
  | unnest(List(lst)) = map unnest lst
```

The above won't compile because the final case yields an `'a list list`. How can we turn a list of lists into just a list?

We can concatenate two lists with the `@` operator, and that means we can fold this over the lists to get a flattened list.

```
fun unnest(Nil) = []
  | unnest(Atom(x)) = [x] 
  | unnest(List(lst)) = foldl op@ [] (map unnest lst)
```

Evaluating `unnest(List [(Atom 1), (Atom 2), (Atom 3)])` now gets us `[3, 2, 1]`. This is reversed because of the order in which `foldl` sends arguments to `op@`. If we write an anonymous function we can correct this.

```
fun unnest(Nil) = []
  | unnest(Atom(x)) = [x] 
  | unnest(List(lst)) = foldl (fn (x, i) => i @ x) [] (map unnest lst)
```